# Ajax returning 302 status when request payload is large

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Im submitting a form with some entries. It contains an array. Im using Ajax post method and in the success state, I've called a function to redirect to a different page. Whenever the array size exceeds 30, instead of getting 200, I'm getting 302 status code and the redirection wont happen as it doesn't go into success state. But my db is still getting updated even though I don't get a proper response. If the array size is less than 30, I'm getting a 200 status code and it will get to success state and the redirection happens. Can anyone help me out with what's causing this issue?

Comment: Maybe i simple code with be helpful

Comment: Not without some idea of your server side code and a representative example of the data you are trying to submit.

Comment: it's a server side issue, nothing you can do with ajax

Comment: @AbhisekBera if its a server side issue, then it should return some error right? and my db shouldn't get updated with the new values.

Comment: That would depend entirely on the code running on your server and its configuration. Neither of which you've given any details of. It's highly likely this is a server issue though.

Comment: 302 doesn't mean that there is some error. Sometimes for example there is session checking code in server side, if session checking fails then obviously it redirects to some specified page. In that case ajax will get 302.